# Permissions over an App

Tags: xero-api

I'm new to Xero API's and I'm trying to understand a thing.
In my Company we currently have various different “organisations” within Xero, and this number will be growing in the near future. 
We also have a 3rd party web application we use for technical and management data – to which we now would like to add financial data, mostly in the form of exported Xero reports. 
We had been looking at the API functionality – however as I understand it Xero is unable to grant a subset of permissions to API calls – i.e. anyone with API access would have the same level of access a standard user – so aside from being able to pull the reports we require, they would also have access to all other data, such as transactional data, account numbers, creation and deletion of invoices etc. etc. Please can you confirm whether this would be the case?

In short terms: we need to restrict the API calls to the reports only, is this possible?

If not, does Xero have a functionality where reports can be automatically exported to an external location – such as a cloud service or an FTP site or similar?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: P.S. Is there a way to restrict access to GET requests only?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. Once you connect an app to the API it has access to all the accounting endpoints. Payroll endpoints are the only ones that require additional scopes.

And no, unfortunately there's no way to schedule report exports either. Sorry!